# how to solve list index out of range error Python?

Tags: python

I'm learning web scraping using python.

Here is my first python code

```
# encoding=utf8
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bcsfootball.org/").read(),"lxml")

for row in soup("table", {'class': "mod-data"})[0].tbody("tr"):
    tds = row('td')
    print tds[0].string, tds[1].string
```

I'm getting error

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/NewYork/PycharmProjects/untitled/News.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/NewYork/PycharmProjects/untitled/News.py", line 8, in <module>
    for row in soup("table", {'class': "mod-data"})[0].tbody("tr"):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone help me what am doing wrong ?

And one more thing I would like to ask ...please help me to understand what is happening here exactly...

```
for row in soup("table", {'class': "mod-data"})[0].tbody("tr"):
```

Thanks !! :)

Comment: Learning web scraping using Python is all well and good, but you will also need to learn Python per se, or you'll get stuck on error messages like this. This particular one means that the list returned by the `soup()` call was empty, and therefore does not have a first element.

Comment: Your soup throwing error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 10082: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: unicode literal..utf-8 encoding

Comment: You're trying to use 0 index for element that is not there - your soup("table", {'class': "mod-data"})[0] is None, and you start iterating without verifying it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, Can you please tell me about this soup("table", {'class': "mod-data"})[0].tbody("tr") ? First is searching for table name, that I know then searching tr tags in tbody but what [0] is doing there.? Is that mean its searching from 0 to all tr tags in specific table ?

Comment: If you open the url you're calling and do a view source you'll find no table tags and no class named mod-data

Comment: @dmitryro,es you are right those tags are not there..but if I want to extract the welcome paragraph, how tags would be placed in code ? I'm confused with using tags ...

Comment: So you can see it's div with gradient-containe class then div with class col-full and a p tag within it - so you need to restructure your query accordingly

Comment: soup("div", {'class': "col-full"}) would give you something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would give you the expected result:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bcsfootball.org").read(),"html")

welcome = soup("div", {'class': "col-full"})[1] # we know it's index 1


for item in welcome:
   print item.string
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message means `soup("table", {'class': "mod-data"})` is an empty list, but you want to get the first element in this list.

You should ensure the `table` element has a node using class `"mod-data"`.

Comment: checked now that is not there...but what would be expression of tags in above code if I want to extract welcome paragraph from website ?